# How can I settle div children to cover up the remaining space regardless of the order in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: .]

As shown in the provided image..I want last div with width 20% to settle at the end of the second row. How is it possible? These all cards are rendered by lopping through the data from api

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: use flex and center the items by row. if you do not know about flex box in CSS do some reading on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that: using `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  place-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item wide">40%</div>
  <div class="item wide">40%</div>
  <div class="item">20%</div>
  <div class="item wide">40%</div>
  <div class="item">20%</div>
  <div class="item">20%</div>
  <div class="item wide">40%</div>
  <div class="item">20%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove default styles

```
/* Remove padding and margin */ 
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0; 
}
```

Comment: No.. It's not the problem..Check the attached image, I have to move the last div to cover the remaining space in second row..